# Loop optimization for random process

Tags: python, performance, optimization

Since I call this code more than 1000 times, is there a way to optimize this code which takes 1.73s?

```
def generate():
    S0    = 0
    T     = 1.
    nt    = 100000
    lbd   = 500.
    mu    = 0
    sigma = 1.

    dt = T/nt
    St  = [S0]  * nt
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
    dBt = np.random.normal(0, sqrtdt, nt)

    for k in xrange(1, nt):
        dSt = lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt + sigma * dBt[k]
        St[k] = St[k-1] + dSt
    return St
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com  ... probably is a better place for this ... but almost certainly ... no one knows what your doing with it though .... you may want to explain in english what you are calculating

Comment: do you run the `generate()` function 1000 times?

Comment: Question!, Does your St[k-1] always remains 0. Then you can replace it with 0. That means you can replace the whole lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt by 0.

Comment: @Soumya : lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt is not equal to zero but to lbd * St[k-1] * dt which is almost sure different from 0.

Comment: @James : That's true. Because I have to generate path for St more than 1000 times

Comment: @Joran Beasley : It's an Ornstein Uhenlbeck process. I didn't know the codereview.stackexchange.com. Thanks for that.

Comment: `St[k-1]` is looked up twice.  Keeping a temporary variable `previous` would help.  Set `previous = 0` before the loop.  Change the loop body to `previous = st[k] = previous + lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt + sigma * dBt[k]`.  This also gets rid of the temporary variable `dSt`.  Not sure it will be much of a speedup, but there should be some effect.  It would also be interesting to see if casting `dBt` to a python list would help: `dBt = list(np.random.normal(0, sqrtdt, nt))`.

Comment: @Steven Thanks! This action permits to get 13 sec :) but it's still take 1.60 s :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could squeeze more work out of the `for-loop`, but generating all the paths at the same time (assuming you have enough memory):

```
import numpy as np

def generate_orig(T=1., nt=100000, lbd=500., mu=0, sigma=1., S0=0):
    dt = T/nt
    St  = [S0]  * nt
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
    dBt = np.random.normal(0, sqrtdt, nt)

    for k in xrange(1, nt):
        dSt = lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt + sigma * dBt[k]
        St[k] = St[k-1] + dSt
    return St

def generate(T=1., nt=100000, lbd=500., mu=0, sigma=1., S0=0, npaths=1):
    dt = T/nt
    St  = np.full((nt, npaths), S0)
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
    dBt = np.random.normal(0, sqrtdt, size=(nt, npaths))

    for k in xrange(1, nt):
        dSt = lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt + sigma * dBt[k]
        St[k] = St[k-1] + dSt
    return St
```

Here is a timeit benchmark on 100 paths.

```
In [55]: %timeit [generate_orig() for i in xrange(100)]
1 loops, best of 3: 23.6 s per loop

In [56]: %timeit generate(npaths=100)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.97 s per loop
```

You might also be able to improve the performance of the `for-loop` by using Cython.

Comment: It would be nice to some explanation here why it got faster. The for loop looks unchanged to me; the only significant difference I see is this: `St  = [S0]  * nt` vs. `St  = np.full((nt, npaths), S0)`. So what is the reason for the 10x speed-up? Or did I miss anything important? (Note: I am a C++ enthusiast and can barely read Python.)

Comment: @Ali: Python loops are typically rather slow. NumPy tries to get around this problem by performing the loop in C/C++/Fortran. You can gain speed by off-loading as much work as possible to NumPy function calls. Above, one of the bottle-necks is that the `for k in xrange(1, nt)` loop is being performed 1000 times. What if we could do the `for-loop` just once? That's what the above code does. In `generate_orig`, `St` is list of `nt` elements. In `generate`, `St` is an array of `nt` rows and `npaths` columns.

Comment: @Ali: So whereas in `generate_orig` one value is being calculated per loop, in `generate` an array of 1000 values is being calculated. NumPy syntax just makes it *look* like there is no change.

Comment: @unutbu OK, thanks. I can't say that I understand the details; most likely I should learn more about Python to understand the code in the first place... Well, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Ali: These examples of [basic NumPy operations](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5) might give a clearer picture of how NumPy operations on arrays can look exactly like basic arithmetic operations on floats. Ignoring one-time array-creation costs, doing one NumPy operation on an array of 1000 elements is faster than doing 1000 Python operations (each a dynamically looked-up function call!) on floats.

Comment: @unutbu I came back. :) Please read my answer, I can make it even faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer 2 alternative solutions to [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23412563/341970). What he writes is *The Right Thing™* to do if you don't want to depend on Cython or on a JIT compiler *and* it is appropriate to generate the output `St` in batch.

---

## **[Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)**

I grabbed `generate_orig()` from his answer and turned the Python list `St` into a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_orig(T=1., nt=100000, lbd=500., mu=0, sigma=1., S0=0):
    dt = T/nt
    St  = np.full(nt, fill_value=S0, dtype=np.float64)
    sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
    dBt = np.random.normal(0, sqrtdt, nt)

    for k in xrange(1, nt):
        dSt = lbd * (mu - St[k-1]) * dt + sigma * dBt[k]
        St[k] = St[k-1] + dSt
    return St
```

Timings:

```
%timeit [generate_orig() for i in xrange(100)]
1 loops, best of 3: 25.4 s per loop
```

No improvements so far, same as before. However, with Numba, just by adding `@autojit`:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import autojit

@autojit
def generate_orig(T=1., nt=100000, lbd=500., mu=0, sigma=1., S0=0):
    # The rest is exactly the same as before
```

The timing drops:

```
%timeit [generate_orig(1., 100000, 500., 0, 1., 0) for i in xrange(100)]
1 loops, best of 3: 642 ms per loop
```

I think it's AWESOME! 40x speed-up just for adding `@autojit`!

---

## **Cython**

Here is a Cython version with [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html):

```
%%cython
# cython: infer_types=True
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def generate_cython(double T=1., int nt=100000, double lbd=500., double mu=0, double sigma=1., double S0=0):
    cdef int k
    cdef double dt, dSt
    cdef double[:] vSt, vdBt
    dt = T/nt
    St  = np.full(nt, fill_value=S0, dtype=np.float64)
    vSt = St
    vdBt = np.random.normal(0.0, np.sqrt(dt), nt)
    for k in xrange(1, nt):
        dSt = lbd * (mu - vSt[k-1]) * dt + sigma * vdBt[k]
        vSt[k] = vSt[k-1] + dSt
    return St
```

Timing:

```
%timeit [generate_cython(1., 100000, 500., 0, 1., 0) for i in xrange(100)]
1 loops, best of 3: 638 ms per loop
```

The code is exactly as fast as the Numba version (the tiny difference is just noise). However the code became ugly, all those type declarations make it clumsy. :( Well, not a disaster but still.

---

Both solutions give a 3x speed-up compared to unutbu's answer, which runs in 1.97 s on my machine. However, as I said at the beginning, his solution is the way to go if you don't want to depend on Cython or on Numba. (Both of them have drawbacks; it is understandable if someone wants to avoid such a dependence.)

What would happen if we applied either Numba or Cython to unutbu's solution? Would that result in an even faster code? No. With Numba, there is no difference. Cython makes things slightly worse. Well, perhaps a Cython guru could come up with a better solution...